# Trying to calculate distance between locations using PHP while and for loops

Tags: php, csv

UPDATE: I was able to use Baba's code and modified it to accomplish the task that I was hoping to complete, however, now I would like to write the contents into a CSV file. Everytime the file gets created it is empty. How can I get the data into the CSV file?

I'm trying to create a php script that allows me to calculate the distance between locations. For example (A to B, A to C, A to D),(B to C, B to D),(C to D) where A,B,C,D are pairs of Lat and Long.

The Lat and Long are read from a CSV file and I am hoping to eventually create a CSV file containing all of the location and the distances to each other using php. As of right now I am able to echo each column, but am not able to pass it through the distance function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

distance.php

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
$theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);
if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
} else if ($unit == "N") {
    return ($miles * 0.8684);
} else {
    return $miles;
}
}

$file = file("geocode2.csv");
$outfile = fopen('geodis.csv','w');
do {list($lat1, $lon1) = explode(",", array_shift($file));
foreach ( $file as $data ) {
    list($lat2, $lon2) = explode(",", $data);

    $line = printf("%f,%f to %f,%f = %f Miles <br>",$lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2,distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "M"));
fputcsv($outfile, $line);
                        }
}
while(!feof($file));
fclose($outfile);
?>
```

geocode.csv

```
bg_lat,bg_long
40.8394936,-73.3203704
40.8297023,-73.0942956
40.8853812,-73.1019428
40.858722,-73.20665
40.7503593,-73.1310993
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this in PHP ?

Comment: Well I will admit I just started working with PHP a two weeks ago. What would you suggest I script/program it in?

Comment: Quick question .. you have A - D but i can see E in your CSV .. can you explain ? NB .. You can use a DB with geospatial support

Comment: Please elaborate, and why move away from PHP? Well the actual CSV file contains over 10,000 pairs of lat and long

Comment: Flat file such as CSV is always slow ... and you don't have to do the calculation in PHP  .. you are not moving away from PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(A to B, A to C, A to D),(B to C, B to D),(C to D)` Is a lot of operations for `10,000` points and i don't advice you should do that in `PHP`

Try using  Database with `Geospatial` support such as `MongoDB`

This is a basic example using

```
(A to B, A to C, A to D)
 ^       ^       ^
 |       |       |
 A is constant for every other element in the list
```

Here is a solution  amusing that the list element in the file is `A`

**My `log.txt` looks like this**

```
40.8394936,-73.3203704
40.8297023,-73.0942956
40.8853812,-73.1019428
40.858722,-73.20665
40.7503593,-73.1310993
```

Thus `40.8394936,-73.3203704` would be `A`

**The Code**

```
// Load Files
$file = new SplFileObject("log.txt");

// Get A ( The first Lat , Lon )
list($lat1, $lon1) = explode(",", $file->fgets());

// Loop
while (!$file->eof()) {
    // Get Other Lat , Lon )
    list($lat2, $lon2) = explode(",",  $file->fgets());

    // Get Distance and print result
    printf("%f,%f to %f,%f = %f KM \n",
        $lat1,$lon1,
        $lat2,$lat2,
        distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, "K")
    );
}
```

**Output**

```
40.839494,-73.320370 to 40.829702,40.829702 = 19.049914 KM 
40.839494,-73.320370 to 40.885381,40.885381 = 19.063217 KM 
40.839494,-73.320370 to 40.858722,40.858722 = 9.800795 KM 
40.839494,-73.320370 to 40.750359,40.750359 = 18.763195 KM
```

**Distance Function**

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code does work for (A to any variable), but it does not go back and calculate the distances to each other. (B-C)(B-D)...(X-Z)

Comment: Yes i know ... That is a lot of operation do in PHP

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem, the script will work well from what I see, but do not know how to compare one line to another, right? bone A to B

EDIT:

My answer.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2, $miles = true)
{

return round((acos(sin(deg2rad ($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad ($lat2)) + 
             cos(deg2rad ($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad ($lat2)) * 
             cos(deg2rad ($lng1) - deg2rad ($lng2))) * 6378),2);

}  

$file = fopen('geocode.csv','r');

$data0 = array();

while(($data = fgetcsv($file,0,",")) !== FALSE){
array_push($data0, $data);

}

$num = count($data0);
$data1 = $data0;

for ($x=0; $x < $num; $x++) {
for ($x2=0; $x2 < $num; $x2++) {

    echo $data0[$x][0].','.$data0[$x][1].' - ' .$data1[$x2][0]. ','.$data1[$x2][1]. '  =  '.
    distance($data0[$x][0],$data0[$x][1],$data1[$x2][0],$data1[$x2][1])."<br>";
}


 }

fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: with this modification of the code you can compare all the points: A to A, A to B, B to A. B to C, C to A etc ...